# Alternative to toArray()?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple route where I am using toArray() to return data to an extenral application, and it works, but I just want to return json objects and not return them as an array.

Here is my code, is there a way to return the same data, but just not as an array?

```
app.get("/test/", (request, response) => {
    collection.find( {"DataSet":"somevalue"}).limit(3).toArray((error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            return response.status(500).send(error);
        }
        response.send(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: So you want a single document to be sent which holds all data?

Comment: "I just want to return json objects and not return them as an array". Can you provide an example of what you mean here?

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to return the query result (mongoDB?) it should be as follows

```
app.get("/test/", (request, response) => {
   response.send(collection.find( {"DataSet":"somevalue"} ).limit(3))
});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/actions/collection.find/

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB typically handles query results via a "cursor" object by default. The `toArray()` method simply takes that cursor and retrieves all of the results in an array.

It looks like you're using the Node.js driver, right? In that case, you can simply iterate over the cursor instead via [each()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each) or grab objects individually via [nextObject()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#nextobject).

Both of those links direct you to different sections of the same documentation page for the cursor object. More information on operations that can be performed on cursors can be found there as well. I highly recommend digging into that documentation a bit more.